# I have a card swipe hardware and want to handle card payments via Android tablet

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a card swipe hardware which can read card details and transfer details back to my app running on android over bluetooth.
I want to process this card for payment for e-cart application.

Do i need to use a payment gateway ? 
If i want to talk to the bank directly from my application ..what protocols are needed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with your bank if they support open bank api. If they do you can use that to conmect else payment gateway is your option; in that case you dont even need that reader. I would prefer using payment gateway since all the heavy lifting of encryption, 3d security and confirming transaction like things are done by them. You can just use those apis into your code directly.